# Android Webview setinitialscale NOT work

Tags: android, html, webview

I have a webview and i want to set the scale of it

but setinitialscale fail no matter i put 
setinitialscale(50) or setinitialscale(300)

Setinitialscale works if i load external website.

But not for loading a local html file in asset.

Will this related to the html of the web i load? Anyone have idea for this?

```
    mWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    websettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    websettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    websettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    mWebView.setInitialScale(1);
```

The html as following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="contentContainer">
        <div class="titleHeader fontSize"><div class="boxContent">Diabetic Foot Problems
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="txtContent fontSize marginLR">
            <b>Management</b><br/>

            <li>Advise on proper footwear</li>
            <li>Discuss the need for additional support</li>
            <li>Treat all skin infections( frequent wound dressing/ debridement/ administration of broad spectrum antibiotics)</li>
            <li>Perform annual assessment</li>
        </div>
    </div>  

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This line is overriding the set initial scale method. If you can remove it you should be able to set scale correcty.

```
 websettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```